# MDADM RAID-1 "not large enough to join array" on identical partition tables

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, raid1

I have two disks with identical partition tables (`sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sudo sfdisk /dev/sdb`) that `mdadm` refuses to merge as a RAID-1 array.

```sh
$ sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 not large enough to join array
```

Any ideas about what's going on here?

---

#### Details

```sh
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Thu Mar 22 19:34:24 2018
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 976627712 (931.38 GiB 1000.07 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 976627712 (931.38 GiB 1000.07 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Tue Aug 25 11:56:19 2020
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : hostname:0  (local to host hostname)
              UUID : xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx
            Events : 459187

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       1       8        1        1      active sync   /dev/sda1
```

```sh
$ sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print
Model: XXX (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End          Size         Type     File system  Flags
 1      2048s  1948268543s  1948266496s  primary               raid

$ sudo parted /dev/sdb unit s print
Model: XXX (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1953519616s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End          Size         Type     File system  Flags
 1      2048s  1948268543s  1948266496s  primary               raid
```

```sh
$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx
           Name : hostname:0  (local to host hostname)
  Creation Time : Thu Mar 22 19:34:24 2018
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 1948004352 (928.88 GiB 997.38 GB)
     Array Size : 976627712 (931.38 GiB 1000.07 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953255424 (931.38 GiB 1000.07 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=18446744073704300544 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Aug 25 12:39:03 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : f47ecd0c - correct
         Events : 459193


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx
           Name : hostname:0  (local to host hostname)
  Creation Time : Thu Mar 22 19:34:24 2018
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 1948004352 (928.88 GiB 997.38 GB)
     Array Size : 976627712 (931.38 GiB 1000.07 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953255424 (931.38 GiB 1000.07 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=18446744073704300544 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Aug 25 10:03:24 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 4e58ad84 - correct
         Events : 81346


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : A. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Comment: The `Events` counters indicate that `/dev/sdb1`, if it was ever in this array (can't tell with the xxx'ed out UUIDs), was long ago kicked out of it.  81,346 is much, much less than 459,193.  You may be able to go back in your logs and see when MD forced it out.  The answerer below may actually be correct about the partitions... it would explain the size confusion.

Comment: @MikeAndrews The drive was failing, I took it out and, in short, forgot about replacing it. I leave the question open if anyone is having insights for the future world but I concluded it to be faster to rebuild the array than to find the answer to this one.

Answer (score 0):

You probably originally built the array with the whole disks, without any partitions. You then later probably added a partition table, which messes things. MADM expects a
whole disk.

You should consider the metadata format which may not tell if the raid metadata is supposed to apply to the whole disk or only partition. You could rebuild the array using the newer metadata format.

You could create a new RAID array with the second drive as the sole active volume spanning the whole partition minus a few MB as a safety margin in case this problem happens again. Then copy all the data from the old array to the new one.

Finally wipe the original array and then add the old disk to the new array.

Comment: MDADM is also fine with partitions and I'm "pretty sure" that I built the array on partitions. Do you know how to verify that?

Comment: Please check the version of metadata format. Older versions have this type of confusion occurring. Anyway, the new RAID method is the actual sure solution to go for.

Comment: The format is of version 1.2, as posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. The culprit was that I re-arranged some partitions on the disk BUT the (too small) size of the partition was reflecting the one already deleted. I had to trigger re-reading of the current disk partition table with enlarged partition.

`$ sudo partprobe /dev/sdb # to re-read current partition table of the device`